# How to write Java system.out 'helper'?

Tags: java, io, stream, output

Java/programming newbie learning a little of it in school and I am wondering if there is a 'standard' or preferred way of 'wrapping' System.out.xxx to either overload some output functions or if nothing else simplify the code a little if anyone has any tips.

I assume this is common knowledge I just don't have, but I may not have been asking the question right as (little) searching turned up less results.

I was going to extend PrintStream into MyPrint and instantiate with super(System.out), but to be frank have no real reason for doing so other than it being my first idea.  Thanks much for any help or arrows in the right direction.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Are you searching for some logging libraries (log4j, logback, ...) ? Or maybe some formatting options ?

Comment: Except for debugging, `System.out` is pretty rarely used, and in 99+% of usages this is `System.out.println()` anyway -- you cannot really do more simple than that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to extend the `System.out.println`, but you can set a `PrintStream` to the `System.out` by the method [System.setOut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29), or you can create a wrapper class like the example below to do something before the print.

```
public class SysoutWrapper {

    public static void println(Object text){
        //do whaterever you desire here
        System.out.println(text);
    } 

}
```

Usage:

```
  import static SysoutWrapper.println;
  ...

  println("some message to print");
```